# How to set up load balancing with nginx and Gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, configuration, load-balancing, gunicorn

I set up a Django server using nginx, Gunicorn and Ubuntu 14.04. Now, I need to enable nginx as load balancer. However, I couldn't find anything related to this on the web and I am unclear how to enable load balancing on nginx with gunicorn being part of my upstream block.

According to the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html), load balancing requires at least the following basic setup:

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server srv1.example.com;
        server srv2.example.com;
        server srv3.example.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        }
    }
}
```

This setup is clear and understood. My configuration with gunicorn looks like this and contains a reference to the gunicorn.sock file.

```
http {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server unix:/home/myapp/run/stage/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    } 
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://myapp1;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

It would be great, if you could please help me with the following questions:

1. Is the following upstream block correct to enable load balancing in this setup?
2. Or: do I have to reference to the .sock file on other servers instead of using e.g., srv2.example.com
3. Do I have to add a similar block to all my servers or just to one server?

   ```
   upstream myapp1 {
       server server unix:/home/myapp/run/stage/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
       server srv2.example.com;
       server srv3.example.com;
   }
   ```

Hope somebody has done this before.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: Load balancing usually means one front server (nginx) and several back servers (gunicorns). I can't see where is your back servers beside one in `unix:/home/myapp/run/stage/gunicorn.sock`

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you for your reply. unix:/home/myapp/run/stage/gunicorn.sock is on the same machine as nginx. Are you saying, nginx should be an own machine that links to several other servers with gunicorn?

Comment: I mean, if you have only one backend server, what is load balancing then?

Comment: That's why I am asking. Even if I do have other servers, I do not know what to put into nginx configuration files to start balancing. Rephrased question: how does the nginx configuration need to look like on each server to enable load balancing, considering that I use gunicorn.

Comment: If you have other servers, you add them to `upstream` as `server host:port;`. Also you'll have to make your app to listen TCP port instead of unix domain socket, because latter is only accessible from the same machine.